# Mysql Query Help - Needed

Tags: mysql, database

Table :  taxonomy_term_data

```
tid   name
7     desert
10    indian
```

Table : taxonomy_index

```
nid   tid
13     7
10     7
10     10
12     7
14     10
```

I need a mysql query to get the nid which has "desert" and also "Indian".
Here the output is nid = 10.
can someone help in writing query. I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT nid
FROM  taxonomy_index
JOIN taxonomy_term_data USING (tid)
WHERE name IN ('desert', 'indian')
GROUP BY nid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tid)  = 2
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36ead/4)

Comment: This Works....SELECT nid
FROM  taxonomy_index
JOIN taxonomy_term_data USING (tid)
WHERE name IN ('desert', 'indian')
GROUP BY nid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 1):

You can get this answer via GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
SELECT nid
FROM taxonomy_index
WHERE tid IN (7, 10)
GROUP BY nid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: This Works.... Thanks. My search criteria will be using the name " Desert & indian ". How to combine these two tables & get the result

Comment: This works.. SELECT nid
FROM  taxonomy_index
JOIN taxonomy_term_data USING (tid)
WHERE name IN ('desert', 'indian')
GROUP BY nid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 1):

you can writ it in various SQL writing style as follow:

1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(i.nid)
FROM taxonomy_index i
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data d
ON i.tid = d.tid
AND (d.name = 'desert'
OR d.name = 'indian')
```

2.

```
SELECT i.nid
FROM taxonomy_index i
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data d
ON i.tid = d.tid
AND (d.name = 'desert'
OR d.name = 'indian')
GROUP BY nid
```

3.

```
SELECT i.nid
FROM taxonomy_index i, taxonomy_term_data d
WHERE i.tid = d.tid
AND d.name IN ('desert', 'indian')
GROUP BY nid
```

4.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(nid)
FROM taxonomy_index
WHERE (tid = 7 
OR tid = 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `(nid, tid)` combination is unique:

```
SELECT ta.nid
FROM taxonomy_index AS ta
  JOIN taxonomy_index AS tb
    ON tb.nid = ta.nid
WHERE ta.tid = 7
  AND tb.tid = 10
```